# How to protect measurement equipment channels from ESD?

Tags: oscilloscope, esd, test-equipment, terminal, vna

I was wondering what is the best way to protect measurement equipment, when handling like oscilloscopes/spectrum analyzers/Vnas/sensitive circuits (especially when stored in (none esd) foam)?

I was thinking of buying end caps for some equipment but not sure what to use. Is it better to use a cap that shorts, has an open, 50ohm terminator or a high resistive value?

Comment: These instruments usually have a hard faceplate that cover the entire front for storage.

Comment: I started out thinking that encapsulating the measurement equipment inside a sealed sapphire sphere placed at the center of the **Boötes void** might be the best way to protect the equipment. Should be pretty safe. But is there anything wrong with a [BNC cap](https://www.amazon.com/bnc-cap/s?k=bnc+cap)? (Or if you have time and/or money, then use a feed-through terminator as a cap.)

Comment: @jonk tank you for your comment. I was wondering because I saw an image [here](https://www.eevblog.com/forum/testgear/picoscope-2000/) where the author had some sort of caps on their usb oscilloscope and not sure what he used and why...

Comment: Those may be the feed-through terminators I'd mentioned.

Comment: @jonk I'm not sure if they are really feed-thorugh (if you look in this [image](https://www.eevblog.com/forum/testgear/picoscope-2000/?action=dlattach;attach=297840;image), you can see the don't have any bnc connector). I found [these](https://www.circuitspecialists.com/23-732.html) and they look like the ones used in the images on the PicoScope.  Would it make sense for ESD purpose to use terminators on your oscilloscope?

Comment: I was looking at the one that had a probe connected to it and just vaguely "seeing" what I imagined to be a similar feed-through-looking item on that first one, too. I ***also*** noticed the lack of the two studs sticking out. But then decided that I couldn't be sure about things. And yes, the very first thing that popped to mind is caps with 50 Ohm termination on them. I just restrained myself from mentioning the idea as being pre-mature.